# How to see how many thread is working to complete my task TPL?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

suppose i want to download multiple files with task parallel library and now i want to visualize how many threads are working at the time of debugging from VS2010 IDE ? here is one code snippet which download many files using TPL.

```
var list = new[] 
{ 
    "http://google.com", 
    "http://yahoo.com", 
    "http://stackoverflow.com" 
}; 

var tasks = Parallel.ForEach(list,
        s =>
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("starting to download {0}", s);
                string result = client.DownloadString((string)s);
                Console.WriteLine("finished downloading {0}", s);
            }
        });
```

please guide me or redirect me to any article from where i can acquire the knowledge to see how many thread is running to complete my task.

Comment: Why does that matters to you? Also prefer `DownloadStringTaskAsync` over synchronous version. Because the operation is inherently asynchronous.

Comment: If you are stuck with VS 2010 and .NET 4.0, you should consider upgrading to the free Visual Studio 2013 Community (which is identical to VS Pro) and start using .NET 4.5 which adds `DownloadStringTaskAsync`. Even if you have to support XP (which doesn't run 4.5) you can add the BCL Async and HttpClient packages to VS 2013.

Comment: this is not clear "Even if you have to support XP (which doesn't run 4.5) you can add the BCL Async and HttpClient packages to VS 2013" what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` will default to use the `ThreadPool` as its underlying pool of threads unless you specify otherwise when passing an instance `ParallelOptions` (And passing a custom `TaskScheduler`). You can monitor the threadpool and see how many threads are currently being used by subtracting `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` with `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads`, but that will tell you have many threads are currently consumed by the threadpool, which is being used not only to run your current loop but other work inside your program.

To be more specific, you can use the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` to get the current executing `ThreadId`:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Currently running on thread id: {0}",
                       Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Console.WriteLine("starting to download {0}", s);
    string result = client.DownloadString((string)s);
    Console.WriteLine("finished downloading {0}", s);
}
```

Now, as a side note to your question, doing IO bound work required no threading to be used at all as it is asynchronous by nature. Which means that using `Parallel.ForEach` might cause more overhead of using threadpool threads to simply block on a pending IO request.

What you can do instead is execute those requests **concurrently**:

```
string[] list = new[] 
{ 
    "http://google.com", 
    "http://yahoo.com", 
    "http://stackoverflow.com" 
}; 

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var webRequestTasks = list.Select(address => client
                                                 .DownloadStringTaskAsync(address))
                                                 .ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(webRequestTasks);
}
```

This way there are no blocked threads and your HTTP requests are being executed concurrently.

Comment: i like to know is there any visualizer exist in VS2010/2012 IDE which help me to see how many thread are assign to complete my task concurrently when i will execute the above code from my IDE ?

Comment: You can use *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Threads* to see which thread you're currently running on if you set a breakpoint. But it wont sum the threads for you.

Comment: is there any good free visualizer. share the name & url if u know....so i can download it. thanks

Comment: You can use Visual Studio's [Concurrency Visualizer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/24b56e51-fcc2-423f-b811-f16f3fa3af7a).